# How can I reach my subclass? C++

Tags: c++

In the following code I can't reach my subclass.  I have to have my subclass underneath the superclass to inherit it, but the superclass won't know what to point to unless the subclass is defined before it.

```
class ParticleSystem
{
    Particle *ptr_to_particles;

    void update()
    {  // Loop through number of particles
       // and call their update method.
      ptr_to_particles[i].update();
    }
}

class Particle : public ParticleSystem      //Inherits ParticleSystem
{
    void update();
}
```

Or if anyone can offer suggestions about how to do it differently, I welcome it.  Thanks.

Comment: You should learn more about inheritance, `ParticleSystem` doesn't sound like something a `Particle` should inherit from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should reconsider your design. A `ParticleSystem` should **have** a number of `Particle` (e.g. `std::vector<Particle>`). It doesn't seem correct for a `Particle` to **be a type of** `ParticleSystem`. Something like this

```
class Particle
{
public:
    void update();
};

class ParticleSystem
{
public:
    void update()
    {
        for (auto particle : _particles)
        {
            particle->update();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Particle*> _particles;
};
```

Comment: I see.  But if the particles are part of the system, aren't they going to share the members of the particle system like speed and position?  Cause I thought the particles follow the system which you then change.

Comment: `speed` and `position` should not be members of `ParticleSystem` in the first place, those sound like they should be members of `Particle`. The `ParticleSystem` should have meta-information like number of particles, system domain, boundaries, external forces, etc.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice speed and position of a system are calculated taking into account speed and position of all particles in the system. Applying a change (like a force) to the system means applying that change to every particle of the system.

Comment: If you had like a group of smoke sprites, I thought it would make sense to move a single position and then have all the individual particles follow that one reference point.  I must be wrong.  I'm going to go read up on composition.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice In that case, you have a method move() in the system that just move()s all particles belonging to it.

Comment: And on that note, [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is going to be your friend

Comment: @TitoneMaurice if this answer helped you, mark it as accepted, so that everyone knows that this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably change your design. A `Particle` is not a logical subtype of a `ParticleSystem`. A `ParticleSystem` is just a composition of `Particle`s, not a supertype of `Particle`.

```
class Particle
{
    void update();
};

class ParticleSystem
{
    Particle* particles;
    void update()
    {
         // forall i
         particle[i].update();
    }
};
```